# notifying bindingSource.position. Using 2 way binding in winforms to select the current record

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

I have a bindingSource in winforms as well as a controller class.
I want to be able to set the selected record from within the controller class using 2 way binding.
That is If the form is displaying and I set the SelectedPerson in the controller then the bindingSOurce should make that person the current record.

My controller code is

```
public class PeopleController : BaseController
{
    private SortableBindingList<Person> _blvPersons;
    public SortableBindingList<Person> BlvPersons
    {
        get
        {
            return this._blvPersons;
        }
        set
        {
            this._blvPersons = value;
            this.SendChange("BlvPersons");
        }
    }

    private Person _selectedPerson;

    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return this._selectedPerson;
        }
        set
        {
            this._selectedPerson = value;
            this.SendChange("SelectedPerson");
            this.SendChange("BlvPersons");
            this.Trace("## SelectedPerson = {0}", value);
        }
    }

   public void InitBindingList
    {
        using (var repo = new PeopleRepository(new OrganisationContext()))
        {
                IList<Person> lst = repo.GetList(p => p.Id > 0 && p.Archived == false, x => x.Organisation);

                this.BlvPersons = new SortableBindingList<Person>(lst);


        } }
    }
   //ect
 }


public class BaseController : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void SendChange(string propertyName)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PropertyChanged {0} = {1}", propertyName, GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null));

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

 // etc
```

I have a bindingSource on my form and set bindingSource.DataSource = controller.BlvPersons

If I Update data values using the controller I will see these changes in the form.
However I cant work out how to set the current record in the controller and see the change in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BindingSource.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158165(v=vs.110).aspx) method and set the [Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.position(v=vs.110).aspx) property to the results of the Find method.

> The Find method can only be used when the underlying list is an
>   IBindingList with searching implemented. This method simply refers the
>   request to the underlying list's IBindingList.Find method.

To implement search on a generic BindingList requires various steps. First, you have to indicate that searching is supported by overriding the SupportsSearchingCore property. Next, you have to implement the [IBindingList.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.find(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which performs the search.

You can use examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25540756/115272) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480736.aspx).

Comment: Actually I was hoping that I wouldn't have to share the BindingSource with the controller. Is that the only way?  It wouldn't be binding really.  Or maybe the position just cant be bound...

Comment: I don't think it is possible. In WinForms the BindingSource serves as an intermediary between the form and data.

Comment: @jacobseleznez, I came up with an idea, that seems to be working. I will change it to the answer in a few days. If you agree with it you may like to offer it as the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't want a winforms reference in my controller class, I don't want to share the bindingSource between the form and the controller.

Instead I came up with the idea of having a RecordPosition property in the controller and binding it to a textbox

In my form I have

```
BindHelper.BindText(this.textRecordPosition,this.controller,"RecordPosition");

private void textRecordPosition_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.bindingSource.Position = Convert.ToInt32(textRecordPosition.Text) -1;
    }

private void bindingSource_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.controller.RecordPosition = this.bindingSource.Position + 1;
    }
```

In my controller I have

```
    public int RecordPosition
    {
        get
        {
            return this._position;
        }

        set
        {
            this._position = value;
            this.SendChange("RecordPosition");
        }
    }
```

In my BindHelper class I have

```
public static void BindText(TextBox box, object dataSource, string dataMember)
    {
        var bind = new Binding("Text", dataSource, dataMember, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        box.DataBindings.Add(bind);
    }
```